# Implementing accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift2

I'm attempting to implement `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` in Swift 2 on a `UITableViewController`.

As I explain below, I think I'm missing something in when I create the `disclosureIndicator`, but I don't know what. It gets drawn from code, but my target action doesn't get called. UGH!

To do this programmatically, my understanding is I need to add the detailDisclosure indicator in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` before my `cell` is returned. I'm doing that as follows:

```
// Create disclosure indicator button in the cell
let disclosureIndicatorButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
disclosureIndicatorButton.addTarget(self, action: "disclosureIndicatorPressed:event:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
customCell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
```

In my code, the detailDisclosure chevron gets drawn, but the target action method I assigned to it doesn't get called.

Then I need to create a handler for the button when it's pressed:

```
func disclosureIndicatorPressed(sender: UIButton, event: UIControlEvents) {
    print("disclosure button pressed")
    // convert touches to CGPoint, then determine indexPath
    // if indexPath != nil, then call accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath
}
```

Finally `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` contains code to perform the segue, which I can do. What am I missing?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Not sure why you are adding disclosure button indicator like that in code.

What you are looking for is simply 2 step process -

**Step 1 :** Add correct `accessoryType` on cell:

```
cell.accessoryType = .DetailDisclosureButton
```

**Step 2 :** Take action when the button is tapped by creating the `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    doSomethingWithItem(indexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: That was my problem. `DisclosureIndicator` is just eye candy, doesn't do anything other than get drawn. The `DetailDisclosureButton` actually can has actions tied to it. Thank you for getting me squared away.

Comment: Glad it helped! Cheers :)!